# Rails 3.2 - What is the name of a variable declared in model (Model::VARIABLE) and is there a better practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, variables, design-patterns

In my app I have been using the following pattern to store data that is used in a signup form:

```
class MyModel

  ...

  LOCATIONS = { "Virginia" => "[Richmond, Virginia Beach]",
                "Georgia"  => "[Atlanta, Savannah]" }

end

# form

= f.select :location, Worker::LOCATIONS
```

My questions are: 1) is there a name for this `Worker::LOCATIONS` variable and 2) is there a better practice? Some of my select fields have quite a bit of data and my `my_model.rb` field is getting pretty long because of it.

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Ruby_Variables

Comment: That looks like the sort of data you should store in the database.

Answer (score 0):

They're just called constants in ruby. It's perfectly fine to use constants but in this case you're putting a lot of view related code in your models which is bad practice.

I would suggest you look at using presenters, which are a separate type of object from models and are used specifically for storing view related code. Alternatively you could just put that stuff in a helper (this is fine for smaller projects).

Hope this helps.